# Grothendieck group of a variety and Grothendieck group of its derived category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $K$.
Let $K_0(X)$ denote the Grothendieck group of the abelian category of coherent sheaves on $X$.
Let $\newcommand{\Pf}{\mathbf{Pf}}K_0(\Pf(X))$ denote the Grothendieck group of the triangulated category of perfect complexes of sheaves on $X$, or equivalently the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves.

It is well-known that $K_0(X)$ and $K_0(\Pf(X))$ are isomorphic.
I would like to cite a reference for this fact, but I can't find one.
Does anyone know a place where this is proved?

Comment: Doesn't the equivalence relation imply that in $K_0(Pf(X))$ we have $[\mathcal{F}^\bullet ]=\sum (-1)^j [\mathcal{F}^j]$? If so, it seems immediate from the construction that they consist of literally the same thing (maybe it would be more proper to say that there is a "canonical identification"?).

Comment: @Matt, exactly, but it would be nice to just have a reference to cite.